# How to prevent a specific composer package from being updated?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've made custom changes to a package (Its wrong, I know) and I want to preseve these changes every time I update composer .. How can I?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I would fork it upstream and add your own forked repo as a repository in composer.json. That gives you the ability to apply and test your changes. Via https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

Comment: Check out documentation for a [.lock file. ](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski dies this prevents others that depend on it from asking for and installing the original ?

Comment: @Naughty.Coder No, because you wouldn't submit your fork to packagist. No one else would know about it unless they found it on GitHub (or wherever) You would just make composer.json aware of its location in your project. Of course you're also on the hook for pulling in new upstream changes and applying your change. This would all be a last resort for me though - have you exhausted possibilities for simply extending the package's classes to incorporate your behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Tag that version in your own repository and depend on the tag without any wildcards. Composer will never try to grab a different commit then.

If you are unsure which version to use, and the upstream project didn't release a tagged version yet, start with `0.0.0`. If you are basing your work on top of a tagged release `X.Y.Z`, you might tag your changes as `X.Y.Z.1` and depend on that exact version.